# What needs to be done for an action submission?

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing a google smart home action.On the Google Home App, I can set up my test action. I can use the Google Home mini turn on my devices. I used a C++ server as fulfillment (url: https://xxxx.xxx.com/google/smarthome). My server can receive and process SYNC, QUERY and EXECUTE methods.

When I running the SMARTHOME-WASHER demo. It used firebase and homegraph. I can see the washer status data in firebase database. I can see the functions in firebase, such as fakeauth, faketoken, reportstate, requestsync and smarthome. Evenytime when I turn on/off the washer. I saw reportstate and other requests.
But when I test my test action, in my test action's firebase, there are nothing. No status data, no request data.

When I use `Test suite for smart home`, the WASHER-DEMO is OK, my test action failed to get device list from HomeGraph.

So I want to know: 
1. If firebase is necessary when I used my own fulfillment ?
2. How to report state? Request from google server to my server, or conversely?
3. When I add my test action on Google Home App, the firebase database is empty. Is this a issue?
4. What need I to do , if I want to submission my action.

I have been troubled for more than two months. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase is not required. You can use any backend implementation you want. To simplify development, our codelab uses one type of implementation. If you want to use another host and database, then you can change how you handle the requests.
2. [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) is a command you send from your server to the Home Graph. It's proactive, meant to be sent when a device's state changes.
3. If you are not using Firebase for your test action, then you would not see any Firebase activity. This is fine.
4. To submit, you should [follow this guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing-submitting). Primarily, run the [Test Suite](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite) and then submit your action through the Actions Console.